# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el inicio de sesión de Microsoft?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Me encomendaron que para mi página web los usuarios ingresen con cuentas de Microsoft, entonces al crear mi proyecto realicé una autenticación con la plataforma de identidad de Microsoft, pero esto lo que hace es que apenas entro a la página web (pruebas o producción) me muestra el inicio de sesión con Microsoft.

Lo que necesito es que primero me muestre una vista de "Iniciar sesión" y que tenga un botón que diga "Iniciar sesión con una cuenta de Microsoft".

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo cambiar la configuración predeterminada que me dio Visual Studio cuando uso la autenticación de Microsoft?

No sé qué cambiar y no quiero romper mi proyecto, así que quería preguntarte primero.

Este es mi `programa.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>

{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Así es como está empezando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo estoy tratando de comenzar:

```
<form id="form_login" action="~/Home/LoginMicrosoft" method="post">
                    <div class="input">
                        <input  value="Use Microsoft account"/>
                        <span id="ver_clave" class="ver_clave input-group-append">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-microsoft"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
 </form>
```

No sé qué mostrarte, así que todo lo que necesites solo házmelo saber.

Intenté crear una vista de inicio de sesión (como el código anterior), y en el controlador cuando se envía el formulario, vaya a LoginMicrosoft y este es el código que tengo:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginMicrosoft ()
        {
            try
            {
                MicrosoftAuthService aut = new MicrosoftAuthService();
                aut.Initialize();
                await aut.OnSignInAsync();

                return View("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: No entiendo esto: `Me encomendaron que para mi página web los usuarios ingresen con cuentas de Microsoft` -> ergo, `lo que hace es que apenas entro a la página web (pruebas o producción) me muestra el inicio de sesión con Microsoft.` => Esto es correcto. Por otro lado, `Lo que necesito es que primero me muestre una vista de "Iniciar sesión" y que tenga un botón que diga "Iniciar sesión con una cuenta de Microsoft".` -> Aquí sencillamente debes tener una Vista común y silvestre donde tengas un botón para llamar a la action que contiene la llamada de MS Identity.

Comment: Claro, la vista de Login ya la tengo, pero quiero que cuando se abra la web no salte directamente a la autenticacion con Microsoft, sino que haya Un login con un botón para hacerlo. Mi problema está en que no entiendo cómo configurarlo para que el startUp sea la vista de Login y no Microsoft. Intenté cambiando el Program.cs o el ModelView que se autogenera cuando creas el proyecto y haces que haya autenticación con Microsoft pero nada, no termina funcionando.

Comment: Sucede que en tu configuración, estás aplicando una política de authorize obligatoria para todo, esto incluye esa vista que mencionas. Un `[AllowAnonymous]` podría ser de ayuda. Por otro lado, percibo que eres nuevo en el desarrollo de MVC y WebApi, este workshop contiene buen fundamento: https://youtu.be/6LZG76aLykY aunque sea de versiones anteriores, los conceptos se mantienen, espero te sea de ayuda, esas 4 horas son un resumen bien comprimido de un roadmap de 27 horas que llevé en lo que su tiempo fue la Microsoft Virtual Academy. Saludos :D

Comment: Un `[AllowAnonymus]` sobre el `IActionResult Login` ?..Por otro lado, gracias! voy a hecharle un vistazo cuando pueda!